How long does it usually take for a French residence permit to be issued for talent passport?
As the title states, I am currently on a VLS 3 month (talent passport) visa. This means that I had to apply for a residence permit within 2 months after coming into France.
I applied for my residence permit on 18 September 2024 and want to hear how long does it usually take for the préfecture to issue your residence permit.
In addition, what are the documents you have to take on the day itself? I recall having to bring your passport and a stamp that costs 225€ to show to the officer.
